# Content translation with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, internationalization

I understand I can use module such as `i18n` to perform string translation. But if I have a large content file, e.g. privacy page, should I break each sentences and do the translation?

Seems it is overkill? What are the recommended way to do content translation on large file such as terms, privacy pages?

Comment: What is **large** exactly (500K, 10M, 100M)? And what did you already tried to come to the conclusion that some kind of  `i18n` won't suffice?

Comment: Actually not large, but I want to ask if putting all the content in json translation file make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can split each translation into multiple files and load each section when a page is requested/loaded

You can use translation file names like this `{lang-code}.{page/section}.json`.

Something like this:

- `en.general.json` - this should contain short and general strings, like errors messages, general forms labels, menus string, etc.)
- `en.privacy.json`
- `en.about.json`
- ...
- `fr.general.json`
- `fr.privacy.json`
- `fr.about.json`

Comment: Is it possible not storing the content in JSON, maybe just plain HTML for each languages?

Comment: Yes, Whatever works for your application. (I usually use JSON)  If you can parse it good